# How to parse Any URL From WebView to IOS Supported URL so Can play Video in "MPMovePlayerViewController"

Tags: ios, video, webview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am being working on a app which play Video From WebView in `MPMoviePlayerController`.
I have Done it for "YouTube" By Parse URL from YouTube Video link to iOS supported URL.

But i can't do it for any URL from Internet. I wants to parse any Video from Internet to iOS supported URL. I have already seen this from some `AppStore` app, So i knew there is some way, But can't find it.

Please help me to achieve this.

**UPDATE :**

I have seen Libraries like "VParser" which Convert Embeded Website URL in URL where you can Download File(Video),
But unfortunately that library only works in amrv7 and armv7s.

Any suggestion or any Library that you guys already use?

Comment: I make a tool, https://github.com/DaidoujiChen/DaiYoutubeParser . You can use DaiYoutubeParser to parse the real video url.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the url is for the video resource itself, not the page the video is embedded in. Try opening up the page source and finding the resource URL if this is the case.

If not, perhaps giving an example of what url works and what url does not work could help us answer your question.

Comment: Ya will check for URL is containing Video. But how can i get original video link from Website URL ? Is there any Parser library that you can suggest me?

Comment: I wish I could help with that, but I have not attempted what you are asking for. My example case is: Get webpage url, curl page source, search source text for video url (probably will contain video extension like .3gp or .mov)